# Number of partitions of $n$ into distinct even parts.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, integer-partitions

Question from my last exam:

Let $r_n$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. Prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i r_i r_{n-i}
$$
is the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct even parts.

For odd $n$, the sum has an even number of parts and each of them has a pair with the opposite sign.
The signs will be opposite because at the beginning with the first element on the left there will be a plus, with the first element on the right there will be a minus.
Then we can remove these elements and the signs will reverse. In this way, for odd $n$, the sum is $0$.

That was the easy part. How can this be shown for even $n$?

Thanks.

Comment: The formula is a convolution of $r$ with itself, so the product of the generating functions posted in https://oeis.org/A000009 (partitions into distinct parts) and https://oeis.org/A035457 (partitions into distict even parts) would be useful (where $x\to -x$ in one factor to account for the $(-1)^i$ in the formula).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{R(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_nz^n=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^m\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
be the generating function with $r_n$ giving the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. The representation by the product (1) is clear, since each factor represents either no contribution at all or one and only one part of size $m$.

Since
\begin{align*}
R(z)R(-z)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r_kz^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^lr_lz^l\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}(-1)^lr_kr_{l}\right)z^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kr_kr_{n-k}}\right)z^n
\end{align*}

we want to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{R(z)R(-z)=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^{2m}\right)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We start with the left-hand side of (2) and we obtain from (1):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{R(z)R(-z)}&=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^m\right)\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+(-z)^m\right)\\
> &=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(1+z^m\right)\left(1+(-1)^mz^m\right)\right)\\
> &=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^m+(-z)^m+(-1)^mz^{2m}\right)\\
> &=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+2z^{2m}+z^{4m}\right)
> \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^{2m-1}-z^{2m-1}-z^{4m-2}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(1+z^{2m}\right)^2\left(1-z^{4m-2}\right)\right)}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
> In (3) we split the product into products respecting even and odd parts separately.

We can also write the product (1) as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{R(z)}&=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^m\right)=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-z^{2m}}{1-z^m}\\
&=\prod_{{m=1}\atop{m\ \mathrm{ odd}}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-z^m}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-z^{2m-1}}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
showing that the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts.

> Thanks to (5) we can now continue with (4). We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{R(z)R(-z)}&=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\left(1+z^{2m}\right)^2\left(1-z^{4m-2}\right)\right)\\
> &=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^{2m}\right)\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-z^{4m-2}}
> \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1-z^{4m-2}\right)\tag{$\to $(5)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+z^{2m}\right)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.